# Linux Router Load Benchmark

Tags: linux, proxy, router, load, benchmark

What tools and methods can be used to stress test a Linux-based router/proxy? On the router Squid, Apache Modproxy and Privoxy are installed. The purpose of the stress test is to determine which proxy is best in terms of load. There are three machines, a client, the router, and a server.

The tool must be able to log a performance period so the results can be graphed next to each other, preferably using `gnuplot` or Excel.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any ready-made solutions, but [`httping`](http://www.vanheusden.com/httping/) or [`ab`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) could probably be useful parts in a homegrown one.

If you're referring to the `cpu load` of the router, you could use something like [`collectd`](http://collectd.org/) to gather the data.

Comment: we are using ab for throughput, we are in need of cpu/ram/disk benchmarks for each proxy service. we will try collectd. thanks

Comment: Could be useful then -- it even outputs [`CSV`](http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:CSV) if needed.